# What does the `-- mean in a folder structure?

Tags: linux, directory

I encountered a folder structure at [raymii.org/s/tutorials](https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Cpp_project_setup_with_cmake_and_unit_tests.html) and I'm not really sure what the symbols `` `-- `` mean. Couln't also find any syntax or documentation on how to write such structures.

```
$ tree -L 2 ExampleProject/
ExampleProject/
|-- build/
|-- CMakeLists.txt
|-- lib/
|   `-- googletest 
|-- src/
|   |-- CMakeLists.txt
|   |-- Formula.cpp
|   |-- Formula.h
|   `-- main.cpp
`-- tst/
    |-- CMakeLists.txt
    |-- Formula-test.cpp
    `-- main.cpp
```

Comment: Looks like it's just trying to represent the folder structure. It appears that  `-- means the last item in the folder. You probably want to google the documentation of the tree utility for more examples.

Comment: It doesn't mean anything. It's just the last entry in each folder is marked with `-- to make the diagram look a little prettier.

Comment: You're thinking too much. It's just meant to look like a tree diagram.

Comment: I just installed `tree` on my linux box (was not on gentoo by default) to test it out. With this said not sure what this question has to do with `c++` this is an OS directory listing utility. Edit: Not on ubuntu by default either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbols represent a polygonal chain leading from the parent directory to the file. '-' represents a horizontal segment of the chain, '`' represents a diagonal segment and '|' represents a vertical segment.

The chain conveys the parent-child relationship of a directory entry and the directory that contains it.

This particular tree shows the root directory `ExampleProject` which contains a sub directory `src` which contains a file `CMakeLists.txt`. And a bunch of other directories and files.